# Десериализация json со вложенными фигурными скобками

Tags: c#, json

Возникла небольшая проблемка при десериализации json с помощью `Newtonsoft.Json`
Суть в том, что я с сайта получаю json-данные в таком формате:

```
{"name1":{"param1_1":1, "param1_2":2}, "name2":{"param2_1":1, "param2_2":2}}
```

Десериализацию провожу следующим образом:

```
prices = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(result);
```

Где `result` является строкой с json-данными
Когда программа доходит до этой строки, появляется ошибка `Unexpected character encountered while parsing value`, которая ругается на вторую по счёту фигурную скобку
Подскажите, можно ли это исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>`

Ну а по факту, посмотрите внимательней на свой `JSON`

```
{
    "name1": {
        "param1_1": 1,
        "param1_2": 2
    },
    "name2": {
        "param2_1": 1,
        "param2_2": 2
    }
}
```

У вас есть коллекция, которая содержит в себе имя (`name1` и `name2`),а уже эти имена содержат еще некую коллекцию с параметрами. Вот и получается, что `json.net` ругается на наличие коллекции после `name1`, ибо по вашему коду, он думает, что там `string`.